# Crystal Reports (MVC4) - 'Database Connection Error'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, crystal-reports

Not sure how many `Crystal Reports` experts are out there but i'm looking for a bit of help if anyone could so oblige!

So When i wanna add A List Do DataSource

```
    List<User> xx = new List<User>();
    xx = _UserService.GetAll().ToList();
    rd.SetDataSource(xx);
```

i get this error Message :

```
'Database Connection Error'
```

Im using MV4 Entity FrameWork + .Net object data source(For Crystal report).

Any Help plzz !

Answer (score 1):

You Designed you report with Data source  `(Dataset)`  and Trying now to send `(List)`

```
   DataSet xx= new Dataset();
   xx = _UserService.GetAll().ToDataSet(false);
   rd.SetDataSource(xx);
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.fdfriends.com/crystal-reporting-with-mvc4-mvc5-razor-view-step-by-step-tutorial/

This is a very easy solution for MVC4 Crystal Reporting. I got success to follow this steps.
You need to use DataTable then List.

```
publicActionResultGenerateReport()
{
    SqlConnection con = newSqlConnection(“data source=SILSOFTU2;initial catalog=BLC_DEV;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=234;”);
    DataTabledt = newDataTable();

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommandcmd = newSqlCommand(“SELECT * FROM Sys_Grade”, con);
        SqlDataAdapteradp = newSqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```